# Angular right way to show loading for different components at the same time?

Tags: angular, frontend, user-experience

In angular 7+ web-app I have a page, on this page, I have 3 different components, I make 3 different HTTP requests in `ngOnInit()` to calculate components inputs. and while I am making requests I want to show loading spinners for each component.

My current solution is, I have some other component called loading-component, this loading component takes 1 boolean input variable, and if loading is true it overlays loading spinner on components inside it. For my page where I have 3 different components, HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <loading-component [loading]="loadingcomponent1">
       <component1 [input1]="input1"></component1>
    </loading-component>
    <loading-component [loading]="loadingcomponent2">
       <component2 [input2]="input2"></component2>
    </loading-component>
    <loading-component [loading]="loadingcomponent3">
       <component3 [input3]="input3"></component3>
    </loading-component>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
loading1: false;
loading2: false;
loading3: false;
input1: null
input2: null
input3: null

 ngOnInit() {
   this.loading1 = true;
   this.http.get(url1).subscribe(resp => {
       this.input1 = resp
       this.loading1 = false
   })

   this.loading2 = true;
   this.http.get(url2).subscribe(resp => {
       this.input2 = resp
       this.loading2 = false
   })

   this.loading3 = true;
   this.http.get(url3).subscribe(resp => {
       this.input3 = resp
       this.loading3 = false
   })
}
```

I compute 3 different boolean variables for 3 different loading-component. Set true before HTTP request, set false after the response.

My question: Is it a good way or is there any other way (better) to handle this?

ps. In my previous project, which was made with `vue.js` I used the same strategy

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach. An alternative would be loading each component separately, and only if needed. For example, by using ngIf: 
<div class="some-container">
    <loading-component *ngIf="loading></loading-component>
    <component1 *ngIf="input1" [input1]="input1"></component1>
</div>
The benefit to this approach is that neither component is added to the DOM unless it is needed. A shortcoming is that the full DOM is not available until all the content has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Other strategy would be convert observables to promises